# Oracle no result from comparing to date

Tags: sql, oracle

I have run this simple query and return no result

```
enterselect * from record where recorddate = TO_DATE(2018, 'YYYY');
```

I have tested

```
Select to_date(recorddate,'YYYY') from record
```

It return ora01830:date format picture ends before converting entire input string

Here is my table structure :

```
create table record(
recordid varchar2(10),
singerid varchar2(10),
producedcountryid varchar2(10),
songid varchar2(10),
recorddate date,

constraint recordid_pk primary key (recordid),
constraint singerid2_fk foreign key (singerid) references singer(singerid),
constraint songid2_fk foreign key (songid) references song(songid)
);
```

Comment: Did you tried by using TO_CHAR('2018', 'YYYY')?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`DATE`s in Oracle include hours, minutes and seconds.
So unless there are any `RECORDDATE`s that are at exactly 00:00:00 in the given month, the predicate `where recorddate = TO_DATE(2018, 'YYYY')` will not find anything to match.

In the second query, `to_date(recorddate,'YYYY')` is not a valid syntax for using `to_date`.  Please see [to_date](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/functions219.htm#SQLRF06132) for more information.

If you are trying to find all the `RECORD`s with `RECORDDATE`s in the year 2018, There are many ways to do so.  Below are a couple examples.

```
CREATE TABLE RECORD (LOREM_IPSUM NUMBER, RECORDDATE DATE);
INSERT INTO RECORD VALUES (1,DATE '2017-05-05');
INSERT INTO RECORD VALUES (2,DATE '2018-05-05');
COMMIT;

SELECT * FROM RECORD;

  LOREM_IPSUM RECORDDATE
            1 05-MAY-17
            2 05-MAY-18
```

Then:

```
SELECT * FROM RECORD WHERE EXTRACT(YEAR FROM RECORDDATE) = 2018;
```

Result:

```
  LOREM_IPSUM RECORDDATE
            2 05-MAY-18
```

-- Or:

```
SELECT * FROM RECORD WHERE TO_CHAR(RECORDDATE,'YYYY') = '2018';
```

Result:

```
  LOREM_IPSUM RECORDDATE
            2 05-MAY-18
```

If you want records from a specific year + month, you can:

```
SELECT * FROM RECORD WHERE TRUNC(RECORDDATE,'MM') = DATE '2017-05-01';
```

Result:

```
  LOREM_IPSUM RECORDDATE
            1 05-MAY-17
```

Answer (score 0):

You will get the result set you want by querying the year-part of the date column `recorddate`.

```
select * from record 
where extract (year from recorddate) = 2018
```